# error 191 facebook api only in some domains

Tags: facebook, zend-framework

I'm trying to make login with the jsdk facebook. I tried with a simple application in my localhost called (**URL: localhost/facebook/main.php**), with that worked writing the same address in facebook.

But my real application with zend has this domain: **http://gamaroff/home** (is in localhost as well)) and not work.....
I know is because of the addres, but I dont know how to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `gamaroff` to the Site Domain for your Facebook app.

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and edit your app to add `gamaroff` as an additional domain for your app.

Comment: I wrote:
APP Domains: Gamaroff
URL Address: http://gamaroff/home

ERROR
App Domains: gamaroff is not a valid domain.
URL del sitio must be a URL with a valid domain.

Comment: Try to use localhost if possible as that is indeed not a valid domain.